MariaDB Cluster Node Locked Out SSH and Login After %100 CPU Spike
I encountered an unusual issue with our Ubuntu-based MariaDB cluster. All the nodes experienced sustained CPU usage at %100-400, and after this spike, both SSH access and console login attempts failed. When I try logging in from the console directly, it reports that the username and password incorrect, even though they are correct.
I'm wondering if the high CPU load could have caused a system corruption, affecting login services or authentication on the nodes. The corruption is being after %100-400 CPU hit for a long time.
Has anyone experienced something similar, or could share insights into how a CPU overload might affect login and SSH functionality on a MariaDB cluster node? Any advice on recovering or debugging this issue would be appreciated.
[mysqld]
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
binlog_format = row
default_storage_engine = InnoDB
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode = 2
wsrep_on = ON
wsrep_provider = /usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_cluster_name = "mariadb_cluster"
wsrep_cluster_address = "gcomm://2.2.2.11,3.3.3.11,4.4.4.11"
wsrep_node_address = "2.2.2.11"
wsrep_node_name = "myserver1"
wsrep_sst_method = mariabackup
wsrep_sst_auth = "mariabackup_user:Password"


Yes, if system processes cannot get the necessary CPU time, they won't function correctly. You should check the ssh, MariaDB and system logs:
sudo cat /var/log/auth.log | grep ssh
sudo cat /var/log/auth.log | grep failed
sudo journalctl -xe
sudo dmesg | less
sudo cat /var/log/mysql/error.log
sudo cat /var/log/mysql/mariadb.log

You can restart PAM and authentication services to recover from failure:
sudo systemctl restart systemd-logind
sudo systemctl restart sshd

The command will show the 10 processes with the highest CPU consumption:
ps aux --sort=-%cpu | head -n 10


This answer is obviously just an approach to recovering the situation after this situation has happened. Thank you for the answer, but the point is to detect the situation that caused it to come here and prevent the problem from occurring at all. This is a terrible situation for a production environment. Also, pam etc. does not work and there is no access allowed to even restart a service. Even options like grub and single mode did not work.

It is difficult to pinpoint the underlying cause without access to the server. Queries that consume excessive system resources can create such issues. For example, I once neglected to include proper indexes for frequently searched and joined columns, which placed a significant burden on the system. In the past, I have also experienced issues caused by overheating or faulty CPUs in the server. I guess malware or unwanted software can also lead to similar problems.
